# NIST STEP File Analyzer and Viewer can not be downloaded

Tags: step

The software STEP File Analyzer and Viewer is developed by NIST。The free STEP File Viewer is convenient and well-known, supports parts and assemblies, dimensions and tolerances, supplemental geometry, datum targets, and point clouds. This software cannot be downloaded from the official website recently.
If somebody could provide the offline installation package?

the official website:[STEP File Analyzer and Viewer](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/step-file-analyzer-and-viewer)

1,I tried to download it from the official website, but there is no link.
2.I Googled the installer for this software, but there is no record expect the official website.

Answer (score 0):

The NIST STEP File Analyzer and Viewer is available again.